# Custom absolute login URL in ASP.NET Core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

Is it possible to specify an absolute redirect login URL in ASP.NET Core 2?
The standard method does not accept absolute URLs

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(x => {
    x.LoginPath = new PathString("https://localhost:88/account/login");
});
```

Produces a runtime error as the URL is expected to start with "/".

The initial problem is that my app service is served over HTTPS, which terminates at CloudFlare, so when user is not authorised, ASP.NET redirects the user to HTTP address,  rather than to HTTPs.

Comment: you can try https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/hosting?tabs=aspnetcore2x#tabpanel_uJoo4eryA3-8_aspnetcore2x

Answer (score 0):

You can override the application host name for each request in the `Configure()` method of `Startup.cs`

```
app.Use((ctx, next) =>
{
    ctx.Request.Host = new HostString("https://localhost:88");
    return next();
});
```

and then in your `ConfigureServices()` method:

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(x => {
    x.LoginPath = new PathString("/account/login");
});
```

I had a similar problem with Application Gateway, which terminated the SSL connection to a custom domain then forwarded the request on to an Azure Web App at the standard http://*.azurewebsites.net domain.

See my original problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49319576/redirect-to-absolute-url-on-timeout-in-asp-net-core-2-0-application).