# Redirect to absolute URL on timeout in ASP.NET Core 2.0 application

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, http-redirect

I'm running an ASP.NET Core 2.0 application which utilises ASP.NET Identity hosted in Azure App Service behind an Application Gateway.

I've set up a custom domain to point to the Application Gateway over SSL which then terminates the SSL and forwards the request onto my backend pool which uses the default *.azurewebsites.net domain over 80.

e.g. **Request to custom.com:443 ---> Application Gateway ---> custom.azurewebsites.net:80**

I've configured my ASP.NET Core 2.0 application to time the users session out after 1 hour using the following middleware:

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
});
```

When the user times out and then performs another action, they're getting redirected to the login page on the app service on custom.azurewebsites.net:80 instead of back through the Application Gateway.

***Is there a way to redirect to an absolute URL on timeout instead of a relative one?***

Comment: Can you please provide some detailed code from your startup.cs.
Do you use a custom login operation with cookie and session, or .Net core middle-ware ?

Comment: I'm just using the out of the box ASP.NET Core 2.0 identity middleware. This works fine when not using the Application Gateway.

Comment: I m not sure if it is true but as far as I search, .net creates redirect uri https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/bee77ebf911d477faed36a12bcc7369bf0005e1a/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication/AuthenticationHandler.cs    

protected string BuildRedirectUri(string targetPath)
            => Request.Scheme + "://" + Request.Host + OriginalPathBase + targetPath;
So you should override Request.Host. 

You can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35628422/override-host-of-webapi-odata-links , especially k0lpak's RewriteUrlMiddleware solution.

Comment: Use x-forwarded-host, x-forwarded-proto, and the UseForwardedHeaders middleware to let the back end know the public host name and scheme. then it can generate correct links and redirects.

Comment: @Tratcher 's solution is simpler, and I think it should work! You should just start typing   "app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions() {  });" with required configuration options and see the magic :)

Comment: @Tratcher looking at the Application Gateway docs they don't supply the X-Forwarded-Host header by default based on: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-faq

I'll give it a go anyway!

Comment: If you're using your gateway correctly, the user/c lient should never actually be accessing the service directly. Rather, the user accesses the gateway, and the gateway accesses the service. The simple solution to your problem, then, is to simply move the session and timeout to your gateway, where it should be, since it's the user-facing component. Since the service is only accessed by the gateway, it doesn't need to know anything about the client or be configured to authorize based on that client.

Comment: @ChrisPratt as far as I'm aware you can't configure application authentication on the Application Gateway that Azure provides.

Comment: @Tratcher I think your solution would work if the Application Gateway was adding the X-Forwarded-Host! :(

Comment: Does it set any useful headers?

Comment: Plan b. If the expected host is always the same then you can assign it inline.

Comment: app.Use((ctx, next) => { ctx.Request.Host = new HostString("custom.com"); return next(); });

Comment: @Tratcher it adds X-Forwarded-For, Proto and Port - but not Host! Let me give your latest comment a go.

Comment: @Tratcher you're a legend. That's worked. Feel free to add an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: Go ahead and write up a clean version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you [Tratcher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2588374/tratcher) for your help on this.

It seems the Azure Application Gateway does not add the X-Forwarded-Host header so adding the `app.UseForwardedHeaders()` middleware was futile. Instead, I've added a configuration value that holds the host of my current environment and overrides the 'Host' property of every request with the custom domain.

```
app.Use((ctx, next) =>
{
    ctx.Request.Host = new HostString(options.Value.CustomDomain);
    return next();
});
```

The ASP.NET Identity authentication middleware then uses this value to construct the redirect URL.

I've also [written Microsoft some feedback on this issue here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217313-networking/suggestions/33657763-add-the-x-forwarded-host-header-to-application-gat), as I'm sure my use case cannot be uncommon.

Comment: Especially cloud environment users should have similar problems. I have voted.

Comment: @MSK Microsoft have responded. Apparently the host is passed through in the X-Original-Host host header by default as opposed to the X-Forwarded-Host header. Could have done with this being in their FAQs :).

Comment: I'm using Azure Front Door and I had the same problem as well. I finally found this and saved my day! Cheers mate!

Comment: Glad it helped @MehmetTahaMeral - although, looking at FD docs, it looks like they support the X-Forwarded-Host header.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-http-headers-protocol

You might just be able to use the out-of-the-box middleware for this.

Comment: Thanks for reply @Jaffacakes82. That's the reason I spent lots of time. But for some reason, that didn't work 

Comment: Haha, thanks for letting me know. I'm about to implement this very thing again...

Comment: I solved this by adding `ASPNETCORE_FORWARDEDHEADERS_ENABLED` in Azure app service configuration.