# NET Core reverse proxy and authentication middleware

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, proxy, http-headers, azure-front-door

I have .Net Core application hosted on an Azure app service, with a custom domain name set up in the Azure Front Door reverse proxy.

External authentication (Facebook) is implemented and works when I run the app locally and when I access the app on Azure directly using the [app_name].azurewebsites.net URL.

However, I get a server error when logging in via facebook when accessing the app either from my custom domain or via [app_name].azurefd.net.

The issue appears to be that, after auth, the user is redirected back to the app service domain (.azurewebsites.net/), instead of the custom domain.

I have configured forwarded headers in the application but that does not appear to have helped.

```
 services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.ForwardedHeaders =
                    ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedHost | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedHost;
                options.ForwardedHostHeaderName = "X-Original-Host";
                options.KnownNetworks.Clear();
                options.KnownProxies.Clear();
            });
```

My login code is the default generated by NET Core:

```
<form id="external-account" asp-page="./ExternalLogin" asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
                        <div>
                            <p>
                                @foreach (var provider in Model.ExternalLogins)
                                {
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="provider" value="@provider.Name" title="Log in using your @provider.DisplayName account">@provider.DisplayName</button>
                                }
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

There doesn't appear to be a Redirect_URI property I can set in the Facebook middleware options.

tldr: my .net core external auth middleware redirects to the azure domain instead of my custom domain even when app accessed from the custom domain. I have forwarded headers configured in NET Core.

Update: edited for clarity

Update2: Have also tried the following to no avail:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                if (context.Request.Headers.Any(x => x.Value == "X-Original-Host") != false)
                {
                    var originalHost = context.Request.Headers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == "X-Original-Host").Value;
                    context.Request.Headers.Add("Host", originalHost);
                }
                await next.Invoke();
            });
```

Comment: By _specifying_ the correct `redirect_uri` in the login dialog URL you are sending the user to.

Comment: OK. How do I do that?

Comment: That should be a matter of some configuration setting or other. If the library you are using dynamically determines this based on a main app domain being set somewhere or something similar, then you might need to limit yourself to using this on one domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same problem with redirects on Application Gateway per the following question:
[Redirect to absolute URL on timeout in ASP.NET Core 2.0 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49319576/redirect-to-absolute-url-on-timeout-in-asp-net-core-2-0-application?rq=1)

Thanks to [Tratcher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2588374/tratcher) for his answer on that question. The solution was to add the following in the Configure method of Startup.cs:

```
app.Use((ctx, next) =>
{
    ctx.Request.Host = new HostString(options.Value.CustomDomain);
    return next();
});
```

Comment: what is options? where do you get that?

Comment: It is how they access their config values from appSettings for example. More here: https://pellerex.com/blog/asp-net-5-web-api-configuration-management

Comment: I added `ASPNETCORE_FORWARDEDHEADERS_ENABLED` in my Azure app  service configuration  and it works...